# How would a nation-state provide an API for its citizens to verify their legal identity online?

Tags: identity

An official nation-state institution, like the Swedish Skatteverk, could easily let their citizens verify themselves online. O-auth tokens could be created by the nation-state institution, generated server-side, and these tokens could be used to verify legal identity within the app-space.

What kind of APIs do nation-states have for this?

**Example market:** there's a host of services that right now scan people's passports, [coinbase.com](http://coinbase.com), [snapswap.us](http://snapswap.us), and these could instead use o-auth tokens generated server-side.

Comment: Perhaps some of [these programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number) have online verification systems?

Comment: @schroeder: I have made the question "non-trivial" by asking "how" rather than "whether," and was wondering if it can be re-opened in its current form. The answer (and comment) are still responsive.

Answer (score 0):

> an official nation-state institution [...] could easily let their citizens verify themselves online. [...] do any nation-states have APIs for this?

Yes, Germany has, as far as I understand, pretty much what you're describing:

https://www.ausweisapp.bund.de/startseite/

However, I don't think it's foolproof, since identity cards can be stolen on the matter-side, and on the data-side a rogue app could log the data.

Comment: This also sounds similar to Nem ID in Denmark.